# Какой графический редактор текста стоит на StackOverflow?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, flask, stackoverflow

Хочу добавить себе на сайт такой-же редактор текста для создания статей пользователями. Вот и интересуюсь что стоит на этом сайте. Пока пытаюсь поставить CKeditor. Если можете то пожалуйста посоветуйте какой ещё редактор текста можно поставить на сайт.
Сайт делается на Python

Comment: Вангую что здесь используется  спецом написанный для этого ресурса редактор

Comment: попробуй Custom Rich Text-Editor